# Daily-level variables and weekly-level variables at the same model

Tags: machine-learning-model, representation

I am running a model which has NPS (Net Promoter Score) as its target and various predictors among which some CSAT (Customer Satisfaction) data.

The rest of the predictors are good to use at daily level but NPS & CSAT are not exactly because on daily basis too few NPS/CSAT surveys are filled in (in my data) so on daily level the ratings are not exactly so representative. (option 1 - see below)

The obvious option is to use all the variables at weekly level to avoid these biases but then I am losing some valuable information from the rest of the variables. (option 3 - see below)

However, I was thinking that I can use the NPS & CSAT as constants (weekly averages) at daily level and use the rest of the data properly at daily level. (option 2 - see below)

Therefore there are the following options:

1. Use all variables at daily level.
2. Use NPS & CSAT as constants (weekly averages) at daily level and use the rest of the data properly at daily level.
3. Use all variables at weekly level.

**Is option (2) actually better than option (1) or at both cases you introduce some significant amount of noise to the model?**